# Does cscope have a query language/api?

Tags: cscope

I am trying to do some deep code analysis on a python2 codebase that is large and messy enough that most analysis tools I've tried have not worked. I *have* however been able to use `pycscope` to generate a `cscope` database. I can even use it to do basic things like find function usages or all functions called *directly* from a given function.

To me, it seems like the fact that there *is a database* and that it *can be used for simple things* means that it should be possible to use it for more complex things too. For example if I wanted to find all functions that are called *from within* a given function recursively, or all codepaths that depend on that function.

However `cscope` documentation is very light and I'm not much of a c-expert. Is there an actual query language for it? An extension that knows how to use the database in this manner?

Comment: Note, I am purposefully not tagging this question with python or c because I believe it is specifically about the `cscope` tool and its db format (which I hear is undocumented) not about the specific language

Comment: Did you find anything relevant?

Comment: I did not @UbdusSamad